# Having more then one Jquery Dialog box and only closing one instance at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui

I am trying to implement multiple instances of Jquery's Dialog box in the same site. The problem is that I have two instances that I initiate with a new'able function like so:

```
function Modal(param) {
   this.modal = null;var that = this;
   var init = funciton (param) {
     that.setupWindow(param);
   }
   this.setupWindow = function (param) {
     var selector = param.selector;
     var params = {} // dialog options go here 
     this.modal = $(selector);
     this.modal.dialog(params);
   }
}

var f_inst = new Modal({selector: '#f_modal'});
var s_inst = new Modal({selector: '#s_modal'});
```

Problem:
if I call f_inst.modal.dialog('close') or s_inst.modal.dialog('close'), this action will actually close both instances of the dialog box.

These two dialog boxes are using two different templates to render them.

If this is a default behavior in jquery ui dialog box, does anyone out there have a better solution?

YUI 2 Container modal widget works very good when trying to have multiple instances of the container widget. I am trying to find a modal that offers similar functionality.

Thanks in advance.

-eric

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to change this to that in all cases

```
function Modal(param) {
   var that = this;
   that.modal = null;

   var init = funciton (param) {
     that.setupWindow(param);
   }

   that.setupWindow = function (param) {
     var selector = param.selector;
     var params = {} // dialog options go here 
     that.modal = $(selector);
     that.modal.dialog(params);
   }
}

var f_inst = new Modal({selector: '#f_modal'});
var s_inst = new Modal({selector: '#s_modal'});
```

I did not test this - but I believe this.setUpWindow is tied to the Modal function which there is only one of, even if you new up multiple instances they are referencing the same object/function

by wiring everything to the that var you will actually get separate instances